# Aligning text between two buttons w/ mat-icon

Tags: html, css, angular

I have been unable to get text perfectly aligned between two buttons which contain a
mat-icon and have (click) functionality.

The two buttons and text are always placed within the row-pages CSS element and used for pagination of charts and tables throughout the application. I have tried as many combinations of vertical-align, align-items etc. as I have been able to think of.  Here is the CSS, HTML and screenshot.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

CSS

```
.row-pages {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
    padding: 1px;
    max-height: 20px;
    column-gap: 1px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    align-items: center;
}

  button {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.mat-icon {
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 20px ;
    width: 20px;
}

  span {
    font-size: 14px;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
```

HTML

```
            <button type="button" (click)="paginateChart('blah_chart', -1)">
                <mat-icon>navigate_before</mat-icon>
            </button>
            <span [textContent]="paginationText.blah_chart"></span>
            <button type="button" (click)="paginateChart('blah_chart', 1)">
                <mat-icon>navigate_next</mat-icon>
            </button>
```

Screenshot

[image]